# mongoimport + dot notation, sub-record merge update with CSV

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoimport

Let's say I have a record

```
{
    _id: 100,
    foo: {
        bar: 0,
        baz: 1
    }
}
```

and I want to update it with **mongoimport** with CSV

```
_id,foo.kek
100,9000
```

However,

```
mongoimport --type csv --file myfile.csv  --headerline  --mode merge
```

would rewrite the sub-BSON object **foo** entirely:

```
{
    _id: 100,
    foo: {
        kek: 9000
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do the partial update

```
{
    _id: 100,
    foo: {
        bar: 0,
        baz: 1,
        kek: 9000
    }
}
```

with **mongoimport**? Is there any other efficient way to do it (I have millions of records)?

MongoDB server version: 3.0.14

mongoimport version: r3.4.2

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible with mongoimport.

`--mode merge` `$set`s the whole document:

```
_, err = up.collection.Upsert(selector, bson.M{"$set": document})
```

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/blob/cb82c3f9336da19b9cafabf7f57e5e5b0e875338/mongoimport/mongoimport.go#L544

The simplest way would be to patch the code to tailor your needs if you have golang set up. Otherwise you can import the file into a temporary collection and merge it using your language of choice, or write own import utility.

Comment: Thank you for the response and for the suggestion. I know I can do it in any programming language provided there is a decent mongo driver,  I just hoped this could be done with some tool or a simple hack.